# Авторизация ВК по лоигну и паролю PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как сделать авторизацию ВК по логину и паролю? Документация вроде требует разрешение на такую авторизацию и то с лимитами. Хочу сделать автопостинг многопоточный. Я так понимаю, надо авторизоваться на сайте через CurL с сохранением куков, потом зайти на получение токена, и забрать токен, далее когда с токеном все сделали, удаляем куки и берем новый логин пароль???

Объясните пожалуйста, какие запросы нужны и есть ли готовый вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте http://vk.com/dev/implicit_flow_user, чтобы получить клиентский ключ доступа, затем вшейте его в код сервера. В scope обязательно укажите права wall и offline.

Это не очень правильно идеологически, но если скрипт делается только для себя, не так уж и страшно.